# Can I sell my activated origin game?

Tags: origin, dragon-age-inquisition

I bought Dragon Age Inquisition, I have all the disks, the problem is that my computer isn't powerful enough for it and so it lags a lot. I've done all I could, but the only way I can play normally is on the lowest resolution, which isn't fun.

I'll buy it on Xbox instead and I want to sell my current PC version, but I already redeemed the activation code. If I sell it can someone else use it on their PC ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://kotaku.com/origin-now-lets-you-return-ea-game-downloads-for-full-r-1169643732), it might help you out, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are one-time activation codes.